# GridView how to show Footer when gridview is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view in which I am adding, updating data. To add data I have used Footer Template. At the page load grid view data source is empty so it's not showing footer - there is property for header

```
ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"
```

But I don't find a property for adding footer.
How I can show footer when grid view is empty?

Comment: what you want to show in footer ?? Image ??TEXT??

Comment: controls to add new row

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=77BdVPLTHpXAuASq6YDgCw&gws_rd=ssl#q=dynamically+adding+new+row+to+gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" Width="550px"
AutoGenerateColumns="false"
Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="11pt" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#C2D69B"
HeaderStyle-BackColor="green"
AllowPaging="true" ShowFooter="true" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPaging" PageSize="10">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="CustomerID" DataField="CustomerId" FooterText="Footer" />
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Contact Name" DataField="ContactName" FooterText="Footer" />
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Company Name" DataField="CompanyName" FooterText="Footer" />
</Columns>
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#C2D69B" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Reference :http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-GridView-with-Empty-Message-and-Header-and-Footer-when-no-data-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Comment: Hope this may help you!

Comment: The TLDR of the article @Krupa Patel linked is that in order to have a footer, you have to copy the HTML of your footer template when the gridview has rows into your Empty Data Template.